# How do I use a virtualenv-based deployment method without upgrading to each and every upstream version?

Tags: django, virtualenv, backwards-compatibility, pip

Last Friday, I've built an RPM spec for my Django project. The RPM creates a `virtualenv`, downloads dependencies via `pip` and puts everything into the packages. Today, I've found out that BeautifulSoup 3.2 has been released. Luckily, I've had my BeautifulSoup version pinned in the requirements.txt, so I found out because of the build failing.

Now a completely different matter is: how do I do avoid upgrading stuff in the future? BeautifulSoup has deleted all previous versions from PyPI, so I can't download a version I've actually tested against. `pip`'s download cache doesn't help here either, since `pip` always tries to check PyPI first.

Can you recommend something to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is an unusual situation. I've never seen another package remove all old releases the way BeautifulSoup does. I consider that rather user-hostile behavior, except perhaps in cases of a serious security fix.

That said, if you want a reliable build process using pip, you really need to mirror all the packages you rely on locally. It's not hard to do; you can use pip's --download option (or your existing pip cache) to get all the package tarballs, then just dump them in an indexed, web-served directory and use --find-links in your requirements file to point pip there (plus --no-index to tell it not to use PyPI).

Comment: Will probably do so or maybe a "local pip light" -- just keeping the zips around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The files in question can still be found: just provide the direct url instead of the package name:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/3.x/3.0.8.tar.gz

for example.